# Magnific Popup close button placed in invalid html?

Tags: magnific-popup

Using Magnific Popup, when my `gallery` displays, I'm seeing that the generated code nests the `<button>` to close the gallery within the `<img>` that's being displayed, like so: `<img><button></img>`. According to MDN's [img tag details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), permitted content isn't allowed, as it's an empty element. As a result, the close button isn't displaying in my gallery.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gallery initialization object, you're passing along an array of markup snippets.  My markup was just an `<img>` tag, but I fixed it by wrapping the `<img>` in a `<div>`.